# Using PapaParse with Angular 4

Tags: angular, papaparse, typescript2.2, typescript2.3

I'm just starting out with Angular 4 and Typescript imports.  I would like to do:

```
 npm install papaparse-angular4
 //Inside csv-service.ts
 import pa4 from  `papaparse-angular4`;
```

The library `papaparse-angular4` does not exist.  So I need to create it.  I'm wondering what the basic outline of steps I need to take to convert papaparse over to something that can be used by angular 4 are?

Comment: do you need a service? you can just use it anywhere in your angular code. Assuming you have it as a script on the page.

Comment: True - Although if I can refactor it to typescript and provide it as an es5 module then it's a better fit for web pack / rollup etc.  The .d.ts definitions can also be made available.

Comment: Well, it's open source. To refactor it entirely, you have to read and understand the source code.

Comment: Yeah I"m going through it right now.  Also found a pretty good article on steps to create esm modules for Angular 4 (http://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/21/distributing-an-angular-library-aot-ngc-types/) .... if anyone has any additional tips they would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your case is pretty straight forward. You can use one of the available quickstarters like angular-cli or seed. Build papaParse into services, add them to a module and export them. Then publish the library on NPM and use it. Or use it from your local or included it in your current repo.

Comment: There already is a module for angular4. https://github.com/Alberthaff/ngx-papaparse 
Just scroll down and it tells you to install it with `npm install ngx-papaparse@1.2.5 --save` for angular4.